# How can I set background color for combobox?

Tags: wpf, powershell

This code shows a combobox without background color. Why this doesn't work and how can I colorize background? What I want to colorize is combobox itself but not its item.

```bsh
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
[xml]$xaml = @'
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Width="400" 
    SizeToContent="Height">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox 
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
            FontSize="12pt" 
            Background="Red"
            IsEditable="True" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
'@
$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)
[void]$window.ShowDialog()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ComboBox Template includes a ToggleButton with its own style,

so you need to add to your window's resources a ControlTemplate with overridden ToggleButton style,

and add to it a Setter for red background.